# Where should I post coding Android questions

Tags: discussion, questions

Should I post them on [stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/) or [android enthusiasts](https://android.stackexchange.com/)?

Here's the question I'm thinking of in particular: [Stopping services in remote processes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29287296/stopping-services-in-remote-processes)

Comment: There really isn't a point in asking where you should post the question *after you have already asked it*.

Comment: Why...it's useful for future reference.  And having a concrete example makes this question less ambiguous.

Comment: You could have simply looked at the scope of each site to get your answer, and anyone else interested in this should be doing that, not looking at your question.  The "future reference" value is zero.  As for having a concrete example, you could have posted a concrete example in your meta post asking if it was on topic, if you wanted to.

Comment: I briefly looked, but didn't find http://android.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic.  And I legitimately didn't know if I posted the question in the right place after posting...not wanting to make the same mistake twice I thought this was a reasonable question.

Comment: Again, if you weren't sure where to post it then *you should have asked before posting it*.

Comment: So posting a question and later realizing that I may have messed up precludes me from asking the question...that's silly.

Comment: You posted both at functionally the same time.  It's not like you realized it a long time later.  And if you had, you'd have already found out if it was on topic or not based on whether it was closed.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

> [Android Enthusiasts Stack Exchange](https://android.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) is for enthusiasts, power users, and regular people who use the Android operating system.

[Android programming questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/android) go on Stack Overflow.

Comment: And please be sure to to write **good** and **well researched** questions when you do ask !, As I see a lot of poorly written and bad questions in the [android] tag.

Comment: @JonasCz, this begs the question.  Is my example good and well researched?

Comment: @StevenWexler Your example looks fine. *This* question looks not well researched. ;)

Comment: "This question looks not well researched" touche :)

Comment: @StevenWexler, Your question is good, I upvoted it :-)

Answer (score 0):

From [Android's Help Center](https://android.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic)

### What about other Android-related questions?

Please note the following topics are expressly ***off-topic*** here:

- Developing/programming for Android (please ask these questions on [Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/android))
- ...

Answer (score -2):

I believe stackover flow will be a good place for you to ask android programming questions. You question should be clear and precise. Don't forget to add relevant tags.